# Failing to generate a hash value

Tags: java, hash, cryptography, md5

In my programme I had to encrypt an optional text entered by a user with an AES key and then encrypt that key with an RSA public key and of course decrypt it later on with the private key. All that works but what i cant get to work is to generate a hash value from that entered string at the end.
I've been googling around for a few days but i cannot find what im doing wrong. A

Here is my code but not the entire one, just the parts where i have trouble
and that's where I create the String inputText1 where the user enters whatever he likes.

```
Cipher aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
aesCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesSecretKey);
String inputText1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a secret message: ");
byte[] encrypt = aesCipher.doFinal(inputText1.getBytes());
```

And then the messagedigest where I use that string again, but it does not work and does not print any hash value of the string. What could be wrong? I was thinking about byte size but its not like im using a huge amount of memory. Any advice?

```
public static void getHashfromString(String inputText1) throws  NoSuchAlgorithmException
{
    MessageDigest mdigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    mdigest.update(inputText1.getBytes());
    byte[] HashBytes = mdigest.digest(); 
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"HashBytes" + new BigInteger(HashBytes));  
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help so that you can format your code more readably to start with in the future.

Comment: will do @JonSkeet but even though my code is not formatted well i could hopefully get some advise concering my problem?

Comment: Well "it doesn't work" doesn't really tell us much. I'd advise you not to call `getBytes` without providing an encoding though...

Comment: i did write that it didnt print out the hash value, isnt it quite clear what my problem is? Iam not getting any errors , thanks for advice though @JonSkeet

Comment: Well what *does* it print out? And what does MD5 have to do with what you've described in the first paragraph?

Comment: From the messagedigest section it  does not print out anything. The rest of the program works well, in other words encrypts the entered string. And Md5 is the hash algorithm that im using..... I just thought you should know what im trying to do with my programme in the first place @jon Skeet.

Comment: You've described encrypting a message - fine. So why are you taking the hash as well? That's not part of encryption. If your `getHashfromString` method isn't showing a dialog, that suggests an exception might be being thrown... have you debugged through the code to see what's happening? (Having `System.exit(0)` at the end of a method is generally not a good start, btw...)

Comment: Because this is something that the teacher wants me to do, its a part of our course i guess.

Comment: But it's not part of what you described as your goal. The goal you described appears to be irrelevant - along with the encryption code. If all that's not working is the hashing code, that's all we need to see... but ideally with a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, along with more details about what you've already done to diagnose it (such as debugging).

Comment: Ok my bad, im sorry.

Comment: Ill try to solve it somehow. Thanks for advice though

Answer (score 0):

If you want your hashvalue turned into a BigInteger use:

```
BigInteger biginteger = new BigInteger(javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(HashBytes), 16)
```

If however, you want the md5 has to be in hex and turned into a string:

```
String hash = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(bytes).toString();
```

In case I said something wrong, that's cause I'm a little bit high right now.

Comment: lol you are having a nice saturday as far as i can see :)
Thanks a lot, ill look into your advice @fihdi

Comment: `BigInteger biginteger = new BigInteger(javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(HashBytes), 16)` seems the same as `new BigInteger(1, HashBytes)` to me (but I'm having a wine :P ).